# Debug .NET Core Console Application with VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, .net-core

My system:

- Windows 10 with VS 2015 and latest updates
- VS 2015 .NET Core SDK
- latest .NET CLI

I want to debug a .NET Core console project and (a step further) a ASP.NET Core with .NET Core project and use the performance profiler.
But I cannot debug both of them. Also a fresh project of .NET Core console app is not debugable. The debugger wont stop at the break point.

Is this not supported or is something broken? Do I need to activate anything?
I have also the problem, that VS2015 is not building the .NET Core project. It says build was succeeded, but if I run the project, the source is not synced to the execution. I have always to run the command `dotnet build` via command line / powershell command window.

Comment: If fresh project of .NET Core console app is not debugable then try to repair VS2015.

Comment: @Sanket I did with the same result. I think the VS2015 scaffolding template uses an old .NET Core (1.0.1) which I cannot install anymore. It always shows 1.0.3 when I install 1.0.1